# Unable to show django form Validation error on same page

Tags: django, django-forms

here is the form

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=("Email"),
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'id': 'inputEmail',
            'class': 'form-control inp',
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'your email'
        }),
        required=True
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            render_value=False,
            attrs={
                'id': 'inputPassword',
                'class': 'form-control inp',
                'type': 'password',
                'placeholder': 'Password'
            }
        ),
        required=True
    )
```

and here is the view for the form

```
class Home(View):
    template_name = "sellers/seller_home.html"
    form_class = LoginForm


    def get(self, request , *args , **kwargs):
        context = {}

        login_form = LoginForm()

        context['login_form'] =  login_form

        return render(request , "sellers/seller_home.html" , context)

    def post(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        name = request.POST.get('store_name')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        mobile = request.POST.get('mobile')

        form = self.form_class(request.POST)


        if request.is_ajax():
            if email:
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps('True'))
                else:
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps('False'))
            if mobile:
                if User.objects.filter(mobile=mobile).exists():
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps('True'))
                else:
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps('False'))
        else:
            if form.is_valid():
                email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
                password = form.cleaned_data["password"]

                user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=email)

                authenticated_user = authenticate(username=user.username , password=password)

                if not authenticated_user:
                    raise ValidationError("Email or password is incorrect")
                else:
                    login(request , authenticated_user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
            else:
                return render(request , self.template_name , {'login_form' : form})
```

the problem here iam facing is that i am not able to show to validation error as a label in the template .it throws error as validation error .how can i achieve the validation in a better way?

here is the traceback

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Grooved2\grooved\src\sellers\views.py" in post
  82.                   raise ValidationError("Email or password is incorrect")

Exception Type: ValidationError at /sellers/
Exception Value: [u'Email or password is incorrect']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django views do not handle validation errors. You should raise `ValidationError` in the form's `clean_<field>` or `clean` methods.

Note that Django already has a built in [`AuthenticationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) that you could use. If you look at its source code, you can see how it calls `authenticate` in the form's [`clean`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/38ddd4ab553fb6b311c62d15fca7d848f84d539a/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L176) method, not in the view.

Answer (score 2):

You are use built-in authenticate method:

`authenticated_user = authenticate(username=user.username , password=password)`
so no need to raise `ValidationError`

Django views does not handle it. You should use clean method for validate the fields.